# How to indicate specific slice of a 3D array in MATLAB using GPUs?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, gpu

I have a 4x4x1250 matrix in MATLAB. I want to find a way to move through the 4x4 matrices slice by slice in order to find the condition of the 4x4 matrices individually.

I don't want to do it in a loop because I want to do this on the GPU and would like it to be indexed.

I saw "squeeze", but I don't think it works for 3D arrays...

I kind of want to use arrayfun, but I don't know how to indicate the specific dimension that I'm interested in.

Any ideas?

**Edit:** I thought the details I gave are sufficient, nevertheless:

I have a matrix A, size 4x4x1250.

I am interested in the conditions of the 1250 4x4 matrices that make up A. So lets say B = A(:,:,1).

I want to calculate cond(B), but in reality I want 1250 of these calculations.

If I do arrayfun, I don't know how to specify the specific dimension of A along which to slice.

Comment: once upon a time with Jacket, you'd use `gfor` and that's it...

Comment: seriously, `arrayfun` is the answer, give us more details on what excatly you want to accomplish.

Comment: Added details, but it's pretty much the same thing paraphrased. I don't know what else you need in terms of information.

Answer (score 0):

ARRAYFUN disregards the shape of the input, and operates in a purely element-wise fashion. There's also [PAGEFUN](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/pagefun.html) on the GPU which operates on pages of an array - however, PAGEFUN only really offers an advantage if you're using one of the functions explicitly supported - otherwise it operates in an element-wise fashion.

Comment: Okay cool! I looked it up and cond() is listed as a GPU-supported function. So I will take a look at pagefun. Thanks!